# TypeError: __init__() takes from 2 to 5 positional arguments but 10 were given

Tags: python, opencv, data-augmentation

i am doing rotation flipping of the images When I am writing Data augmentation codeshown of clipped and zoom function  below

i am creating the function of augmentation of eight types of images

now calling the function but it shows error below and keep all the images in the augmentation folder

```
%%time

# Only augumenting H, G, C, A, M for creating balanced dataset

_image_path = []
_n = []
_d = []
_g = []
_c = []
_a = []
_h = []
_m = []
_o = []

for file_name, n, d, g, c, a, h, m, o in zip(
    list(df_train['image_name']), list(df_train['N']), list(df_train['D']), list(df_train['G']), 
    list(df_train['C']), list(df_train['A']), list(df_train['H']), list(df_train['M']), list(df_train['O'])
        ):
    
    file_path = "Processed Images/" + file_name
    
    _image_path.append(file_path)
    _n.append(n)
    _d.append(d)
    _g.append(g)
    _c.append(c)
    _a.append(a)
    _h.append(h)
    _m.append(m)
    _o.append(o)
    
    after this it shows error
```

it gives error shown below

```
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-47-db5e62aa7890> in <module>()
----> 1 get_ipython().run_cell_magic('time', '', '\n# Only augumenting H, G, C, A, M for creating balanced dataset\n\n_image_path = []\n_n = []\n_d = []\n_g = []\n_c = []\n_a = []\n_h = []\n_m = []\n_o = []\n\nfor file_name, n, d, g, c, a, h, m, o in zip(\n    list(df_train[\'image_name\']), list(df_train[\'N\']), list(df_train[\'D\']), list(df_train[\'G\']), \n    list(df_train[\'C\']), list(df_train[\'A\']), list(df_train[\'H\']), list(df_train[\'M\']), list(df_train[\'O\'])\n        ):\n    \n    file_path = "/content/Processed Images/" + file_name\n    \n    _image_path.append(file_path)\n    _n.append(n)\n    _d.append(d)\n    _g.append(g)\n    _c.append(c)\n    _a.append(a)\n    _h.append(h)\n    _m.append(m)\n    _o.append(o)\n    \n    if h == 1 or g == 1 or c == 1 or a == 1 or m == 1:\n        augumentation_of_eight_types(file_path)\n\n        _image_path.append("/content/Augumented Images/" + "VF-" + file_name)\n        _image_path.append("/content/Augumented Images/" + "HF-" + file_name)\n        _image_path.append("/content/Augumented Images/" + "BF-" + file_name)\n        _image_path.append("/content/Augumented Images/" + "Z-" + file_name)\n        _image_path.append("/content/Augumented Images/" + "VFZ-" + file_name)\n        _image_path.append("/content/Augumented Images/" + "RB-" + file_name)\n        _image_path.append("/content/Augu...

2 frames
<decorator-gen-60> in time(self, line, cell, local_ns)

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/IPython/core/magics/execution.py in time(self, line, cell, local_ns)
   1191         else:
   1192             st = clock2()
-> 1193             exec(code, glob, local_ns)
   1194             end = clock2()
   1195             out = None

<timed exec> in <module>()

TypeError: __init__() takes from 2 to 5 positional arguments but 10 were given
```

Comment: How do you run your code? Somehow the whole code is ran through `exec()` which produces a less helpful traceback.

Comment: no i am running the whole code ... part by part i am running

Comment: It is bit difficult to figure out point where it is going wrong, but you first make sure "all the zip parameters not have empty content" otherwise it wont iterate. and traceback is not pointing to any particular line in your code. It would be good if you put it in the .py file and execute, that would help to debug better in this case.

Comment: When using a mocked ``df_train``, I cannot reproduce this error. Please [edit] your question to add a [mcve].